# Message parsing not working (Linux - Ubuntu)

Tags: quickfixn

I`m trying to make a working sample in a Linux Machine (with ubuntu).
But when the method FromAdmin(Message msg... is invoked, on Windows it parses to a right message type. Eg.

switch (msg)
case QuickFix.FIX44.Reject reject: (On windows it works fine)

On linux it cannot pase to the correct base type.

Any thoughs ?

Using latest version on nugetpackage:

```
PackageReference Include="QuickFix.Net.NETCore" Version="1.8.1"

PackageReference Include="QuickFix.Net.NETCore.FIX44" Version="1.8.1"
```

within:

```
TargetFramework net5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... i found a way.

Looking forward to the documentation i found this:

http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/receiving-messages
(Using the MessageCracker implementation)

That solved my parsing problem.

Hope that his helps someone.

Comment: `if (message is Logon logon)` returns `false` even when the message is type Logon. I will try this approach.